# Resize boot partition with LVM and locked extended partition on live USB

Tags: boot, partitioning, live-usb, gparted

Don't ask why, but I've made /boot partition 243 MB and when I run `do-release-upgrade` it says it requires 7G of free disk there. I've created live usb of gparted iso (using unetbootin). Booted it and see that /dev/sda2 (extended) and /dev/sda5 (lvm2 pv) have key icon (locked or so). Can't resize or do anything. Any clues what to do?

Comment: GParted can handle partitions, but LVMs require a different tool to resize. `system-config-lvm` should give you what you need.

Comment: 7 GB in /boot seems enormously excessive. If that's accurate (check!), then you may have a bugger problem than tweaking partition sizes.

Comment: Are you tryin to do the release upgrade on a live USB?

Comment: no, I tried doing that on my running xubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @Matigo the thing is, I need to downsize that extended partition where LVM sits, and then extend boot partition

Comment: Then you have a 2-step process: (1) reduce the size of the Logical Volume (2) reduce the size of the partition.

Comment: @Matigo sounds promising, I'll give it a go in the evening.

Comment: sorry, I've made a mistake with that 7GB ;) no need to resize